# is there a way to Click OK in pop window on chrome using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am creating a test project where when clicking on a button system pops-up a window where I need to click OK but unable to do using the following code:

```java
@Test
public void testAddNewUserMakeSuperUser() throws Exception {
    driver.get("https://webqa.searshc.com/ssod/Admin/createUser.html");
    driver.findElement(By.id("saveUserDetails")).click();
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    System.out.println(alert.getText());
    alert.accept();
}
```

I have used

```java
executeScript = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.confirm = function(msg) { return true; }");
```

also... but I am unable to run this.

Answer (score 0):

You should test first if the Alert is present on the page before the click.

Like this:

```
    public static bool IsAlertPresent(this IWebDriver driver)
    {
        try
        {
            driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And then:

```
    public static void ConfirmAlert(this IWebDriver driver)
    {
        driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me 
    executeScript = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.confirm = function(msg) { return true; }");

Answer (score -1):

Please look the following link

http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/twist/2.3/help/how_do_i_handle_popup_in_selenium2.html

I hope This will be helpful to you,

Comment: Answers on Stack Overflow should be self-contained. Please include the most significant of the external source in your answer.